# Need help in fixing and creating carousel js functions or css styles (Angular 6)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, sass

I'm having a problem creating and fixing carousel animations. Most carousels are only in 1 per screen while I need 4 per screen so I'm trying to implement my own carousel.

Current html:

```
<div class="display-flex m-t-2">
    <div [ngClass]="{ 'disabled-button': page === 1, 'cursor-pointer': page > 1}" (click)="prev()">
        <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</i>
    </div>
    <div class="display-flex-child width-100">
        <div class="m-x-2" *ngFor="let prod of productList">
            <div class="display-flex flex-direction">
                <div class="text-title">{{prod.title}}</div>
                <div>
                    <img [src]="prod.url" alt="{{prod.title}}" height="200" width="200">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div [ngClass]="{ 'justify-content-right disabled-button': !hasNextValues, 
        'justify-content-right cursor-pointer': hasNextValues}" (click)="next()">
        <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Image here:
[Html code result image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yR0wTOsytGxVzE-zF-uTJUKgt8fuzbmp)

Expected: to be like a carousel that has a delay when clicking next and previous button

Actual: instantly goes to next or previous